# Confusion between boost::bind and boost::phoenix placeholders

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

The `boost::spirit` documentation has this important warning

> There are different ways to write semantic actions for Spirit.Qi: using
>   plain functions, `Boost.Bind`, `Boost.Lambda`, or `Phoenix`. The latter
>   three allow you to use special placeholders to control parameter
>   placement (`_1`, `_2`, etc.). Each of those libraries has it's own
>   implementation of the placeholders, all in different namespaces. You have
>   to make sure not to mix placeholders with a library they don't belong to
>   and not to use different libraries while writing a semantic action.
>
> Generally, for `Boost.Bind`, use `::_1`, `::_2`, etc. (yes, these placeholders are
>   defined in the global namespace).
>
> For `Boost.Lambda` use the placeholders defined in the namespace `boost::lambda`.
>
> For semantic actions written using Phoenix use the placeholders defined in
>   the namespace `boost::spirit`. Please note that all existing placeholders for
>   your convenience are also available from the namespace `boost::spirit::qi`

([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html))

OK, so I write this code

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct ruleset_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
    template <typename TokenDef>
    ruleset_grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
      : ruleset_grammar::base_type(start)
    {

        start =  *(  tok.set_name [ boost::bind( &cRuleSet::setName, &theRuleSet, ::_1 ) ]
                  )
              ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};
```

Please note the use of `::_1`

However, I still get this compiler error

```
c:\documents and settings\james\spirit_test.cpp(138) : error C2872: '_1' : ambiguous symbol
        could be 'c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\spirit\home\support\argument.hpp(124) : const boost::phoenix::actor<Eval> boost::spirit::_1'
        with
        [
            Eval=boost::spirit::argument<0>
        ]
        or       'c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(43) : boost::arg<I> `anonymous-namespace'::_1'
        with
        [
            I=1
        ]
```

How do I fix this compiler error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you maybe write a `using namespace boost::spirit;` somewhere at the top of that file? Because if yes, both the spirit as well as the bind placeholders are now in global namespace. The direct use of `qi::` may support my assumption, but that might aswell be a simple `namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi`.

Comment: I think you are right.  Of course, removing it gives me a million other errors.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: @ravenspoint: If you indeed have a `using namespace boost::spirit` somewhere, simply replace it with `namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi; namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma` etc. for all needed namespaces. :)